# Analysis: Taylor Series. Expanding $F_g$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

[image]

Right now, we are covering the Taylor Series I try to start with the hint but am confused.  It says to expand $F_g$ around $h=0$.
Using Taylor Series does this mean:
$F_g(h)=f(0)+ f'(0)(h-0)+f''(0)/2!(h-0)^2 ..... $?
       =$\frac{-GMm}{R}+\frac{GMm}{R^2}h-\frac{GMm}{R^3}h^2 +....                  $.

And then after this I'm not really sure what to do.  I'm supposed to show that when $h$ is very small compared to $R$, potential energy is equal to $mgh$, where I express $g$ in terms of $G$, $M$ and $R$.  I'm not exactly sure what to do for this nor am I sure what it means to disregard the normalization constant in the hint.  I could really use some help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We can write
$$
\left(-\frac{GMm}{R+h}\right)-\left(-\frac{GMm}{R}\right)=\underbrace{\color{#C00}{\frac{GM\color{#000}{m}}{R(R+h)}}}_{\lim\limits_{h\to0}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}h}}\,h
$$
If $h$ is very small compared to $R$, $R+h\sim R$.

Comment: Hello, sorry but I'm still confused.  Why did you decide to subtract from the function the first term in the taylor series.  How does this formulation relate to Taylor Series?  Thank you.

Comment: The question is asking for an estimate, at height $h$, of the potential energy that vanishes at the surface of the Earth, so we subtract the potential energy at the surface from the potential energy at height $h$. The second term in the Taylor series, $f'(R)h$, is the derivative of the potential energy times the height above the surface.